# asp.net core Creating a TenantProvider with TenantId from current User

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

My organisation needs a Multi-Tenant-solution on a shared database. Based on the example created by [Gunnar Peipman][1] I have created a BaseEntity class with the property `Guid TenantId {get; set;}` The actual `Tenantprovider` has been implemented as a service calling a temporary Dummy `TenantId`.

```
public interface ITenantProvider
    {
    Guid GetTenantId();
    }

public class DummyTenantProvider : ITenantProvider
{
    public Guid GetTenantId()
    {
         return Guid.Parse("069b57ab-6ec7-479c-b6d4-a61ba3001c86");
    }
}
```

I would like to replace the Dummy with the actual TenantId of the current User but I cannot get it to work. I have tried the following, but I cannot retrieve the users' TenantId (created as a property in ApplicationUser).

```
public class RealTenantProvider : ITenantProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    public RealTenantProvider(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;            
    }

    public Guid GetTenantId()
    {           
        var curUsr = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
        if (curUsr.Identity.Name != null)
        {
            return Guid.Parse(curUsr.FindFirst("TenantId").Value); 
        }           
        return Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-000-000000000000");
    }        
}
```

However, `curUsr.Identity.Name` is always null, although a user is logged in. Is there another way of getting the custom property `TenantId` from applicationUser returned?

It looks like 'I am close, but do not have the cigar yet :). Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Hello, were you able to find a solution to your problem? I am facing the same situation.

Comment: @Rapunzo See my answer below. This has worked quite well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue in a different manner by adding code to the ApplicationDbContext as follows. :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext
 : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>,
 ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>,
 IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        : base(options)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);            

        // Add the query, assuring only Tenantdata is shown. You need to do this for every table
        builder.Entity<Tenant>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.TenantId == CurrentTenantId);           
        builder.Entity<Project>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.TenantId == CurrentTenantId && !e.IsDeleted);
        //(..)            
    }        

    public virtual Guid CurrentTenantId
    {
        get
        {
            if (_contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name != null)
            {
                return Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).TenantId;
            }
            return Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
        }
    }

    public virtual string CurrentUserName
    {
        get
        {
            return Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name)?.UserName;
        }
    }
```

}

Be sure to add the TenantId to the Applicationuser (as shown below)

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }        
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }        

    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

}
```